# What is the significance of `-p` flag more than once in a docker command

Tags: docker, jenkins

I am newbie in docker,noticed below command while referring a [document](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md) to install jenkins in docker.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /your/home:/var/jenkins_home jenkins
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-p <source>:<dest>` or `--publish <source>:<dest>`, create a forwarding rule from your `<docker-host>:<source>` to `<container>:<dest>`.
If used multiple times, it creates multiple forwarding rules.

In your example, the traffic from `<host-machine-IP-addr>:8080`, is forwarded inside the Jenkins container, to the service that's is listening on `:8080`.
Exactly the same thing is happening with port `:50000`.

Basically the container's Jenkins web UI is exposed on the host machine on 8080, while the Jenkins slave port is also exposed on you host machine on 50000.

Comment: okay I understood this and tested using command `docker run -d  -p 8080:80 -p 5050:80 httpd` . I am able to access using `8080 &5050` from browser. Again ,why it is used in `jenkins` may be I need to refer  `jenkin` documents.

Comment: In Jenkins, 8080 is usually the web UI, 50000 is the Jenkins slave port. You can change the source port to any port that is not in use on the host. If you want to change the destination port(although you almost never need to do this, because each container has it's own IP and there are not _port conflict concerns_) you need to change the Jenkins Dockerfile and make the two aforementioned  services listen on the desired ports.